# Cloudwatch dashboard insight graphs - can I set binsize dynamically?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I'm using dashboards to monitor various output stats on AWS.

Lets say it looks something like this:

stats avg(myfield1), min(myfield2), max(myfield3) by bin(1m)

This works fine - however I am by default using a bin size of 1 minute - so the data retention period is only 3 days. If I want to look at a week or a month I have to use a separate widget with a larger bin size - I still want the 1 minute resolution for the shorter time periods and I'd rather not have to double up the graphs as the dashboard is already very busy.

Obviously all the built in metrics graphs adjust the bin size they are querying dynamically as the data range being viewed is changed.

Is it possible to do this within a cloudwatch insights query and if so what is the syntax?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.